# How to decode data stored in base64 with "type*:" prefix?

Tags: mysql, base64

How do i decode the following example of base64 encoded string? (it is stored on MySQL DB)

`base64:type251:WXlnY2p0bFl5Z2NqdGxZeWdjanRsWXlnY2`

I have already tried to decode it using normal base64 to no avail. The "type251" prefix should mean something but I haven't found anyting on documentation/googling.

Is there any online tools available to decode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix `base64:type251:` means nothing except to your application. I assume it is some extra annotation to tell the client what to do with the result once it is decoded.

The string you show, `'WXlnY2p0bFl5Z2NqdGxZeWdjanRsWXlnY2'` is not a valid base64 string, because it's not padded to sets of octets to make an even multiple of 24 bits. Read the wikipedia article on base64 padding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding

Trying to decode it fails and only returns NULL:

```
mysql> select from_base64('WXlnY2p0bFl5Z2NqdGxZeWdjanRsWXlnY2') as result;
+----------------+
| result         |
+----------------+
| NULL           |
+----------------+
```

If a couple of `=` padding characters are added, MySQL's builtin function can decode the base64 string, after stripping the prefix.

```
mysql> select from_base64('WXlnY2p0bFl5Z2NqdGxZeWdjanRsWXlnY2==') as result;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| result                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 0x597967636A746C597967636A746C597967636A746C59796763 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

That's a string of binary bytes, rendered as hex digits so it can be displayed in human-readable form.

What does it mean? I have no idea. I can guess that it's a serialized object instance of "type251" which is something specific to the application that saved that data. You haven't described anything about your application or even what language it's written in.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you for the insightful answer. I'll study the function that writes said data.